# ADODB with Crystal report error using c# 2008

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and SqlExpress to develop a windows application.

I have created a database and trying to create a Crystal report using it. But when I use the Wizard to create the Report( as I use OLE DB  Provider for Sql Server) I get the following Error message:

Title of the error message:

Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer

Body of the error message says:

Not Implemented

Details:Error Code:0x

Source: ADODB.Connection

Description:Object or Provider is not capable of performing requested operation.

Can anyone help me out of this problem. I'm a very new person in this field, so it will  be helpfull if you help me in details..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/50edd864-8bd2-427e-8946-05df8aba9e06) thread on MSDN indicates that for some this problem was caused by an unusual database name with special characters. Does yours contain something like . or @ ?

Comment: No, i didnt use any special charactors. I could not connect the db while view the report.

Comment: Thank you :). I had the same problem and the database name include a dot "."